# ubuntu 14.04 pyenv install fail

Tags: python, bash, pyenv

> with command "lsb_release -a",

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Release:        14.04

Codename:       trusty

> I followed this page,
>   https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout

but installation failed.

1. cloned https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
2. add command 
   `$ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   $ echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   $ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile`
3. `source ~/.bash_profile` 
   returns :**No such file or directory**

---

also, my `echo "$PATH"` is `/home/vagrant/.pyenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.pyenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.pyenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/shims:/home/vagrant/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin`

how can I solve this?

also here is my `~/.bash_profile` below...

> [[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
>
> export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
>
> export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
>
> if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
>
> eval "$(pyenv init -)"
>
> fi

[MY TERMINAL PHOTO: bashrc exists and One&only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lREn6.png)

Here is my ~/.bash_profile

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat ~/.bash_profile

[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc

#export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
#export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin":$PATH
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$
```

Here is my ~/.bashrc

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat ~/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/HQSSL.crt
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/HQSSL.crt
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export KAFKA_HOST="10.20.30.33"
export KAFKA_PORT=19092

alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3

alias pbcopy='xclip -selection clipboard'
alias pbpaste='xclip -selection clipboard -o'


#export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
#if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
#  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
#fi


#eval "$(pyenv init -)"
#eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"



export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

Comment: First there is no `~/.bash_profile` and then there is one?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I added my terminal photo. Please understand that I only attached the picture as a link, because I have only 3 reputation

Comment: Thanks, that's a good idea. However, it would be better if you copied the text, because that would even be searchable. Also, does that text answer my question?

Comment: Yes, I tried to attach a link to the execution of the command. List of files that come out by typing vi~/.bash and pressing the **tab** key several times. `.bash_history  .bash_logout   .bash_profile  .bashrc
` As you can see, `.bash_profile`is one & only.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because `.bashrc` file does not exist. Also it looks you are adding the `pyenv` environment variables to `~/.bash_profile` and trying to source the `.bashrc` file.

Try sourcing the file that you've modified

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or reload the shell with changes using

```
exec $SHELL
```

Comment: umm.. infact I have `.bashrc` file now. also I tried to add both `.bashrc` file and `.bash_profile`, but if the `source ~` command is executed, ubuntu returns both no such file or directory.

Comment: Okay. What happens when you execute the above commands ? Could you share the log ?

Comment: If I execute `source ~/.bash_profile`, it returns `: No such file or directory` . also If I execute `exec $SHELL`, it returns none. but still fails `pyenv versions`

Comment: Could you try with absolute path `source /home/<user-name>/.bash_profile` ? Which user are you ? Run `whoami`

Comment: when execute `whoami`, it returns `vagrant`. And `source /home/vagrant/.bash_profile` is sams as before `source ~/.bash_profile` ;-( ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have issue with this command?

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Anyway, WARNING, I think you have a syntax issue in your file, with the quotes in PATH definition, making it think the whole is only one path, you should change like this:

```
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin":$PATH
```

See the modified quotes' position.

Additional information, after your edit:

- there are still badly placed quotes, please update all following
  `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"` by `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin":$PATH`
- you should add safe-guard when using `rbenv`, for instance replace your eval line, by `command -v rbenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && eval "$(rbenv init -)"`
- at the end of your **.bashrc**, you MUST remove useless backslack before source files (and use `-f`, instead of `-s`), at end it should give:

```
    [ -f "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
    [ -f "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

And thus, your final `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` is useless because it would have already be done by your `if` instruction if the file exists.

Anyway, if it is still not working, could you give output of:

```
bash -x ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I think you are right. when execute `exec $"PATH"` not `echo "$PATH"`, `No such file or directory` is printed after the path.

Comment: Yes, anyway you must never **exec "PATH"**. Is your initial issue resolved?

Comment: Cat you execute:
    cat ~/.bash_profile && cat ~/.bashrc

Comment: @Bsqure no answer helps me. still print `: No such file or directory` I can cat ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc

Comment: Yes show us  ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc files please.

Comment: @Bsqure I updated my `bash files`. If i do not comment the confs,  ` : No such file or directory ` so I commented configurations.

Comment: Im so sorry, but I coudnt found the way of copying all of `bash -x result` ... can you wait ...?

Comment: You can redict standard and error outputs in one file. `... >/tmp/myFile 2>&1`

Comment: but none of these are answers.